# MVC Linq vs Model Dot Notation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I just simply am not understanding the a couple of concepts of this simple MVC View:

```
@model Models.Company

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName)
<br />

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Departments, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "Id", "Name"), "Select Department")
```

Note that `Model.Departments` is a property of the Company object that returns a List object.

I understand that the Model of the View is the Company object. What I'm not understanding in the least bit is why LINQ is used to populate the name of the TextBox, why it is used as the name of the DropDownList and why Model Dot Departments is used for the SelectList.

Why not just use Model.CompanyName and Model.Departments? Why bring in LINQ at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m.CompanyName)
```

instead of this?:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName)
```

Because those mean two *very* different things.  The first one (the one you would like to use) doesn't tell `TextBoxFor()` anything about the model.  It just passes a string value.  So the resulting text box would have *only* that string value to use, and nothing about the property or the model which held that property.  No model annotations, no validation, nothing.  It would be exactly the same as this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor("My Company Name")
```

Heck, it wouldn't even be able to tell the `input` what to use for the `name` attribute, which means there'd be no way to bind the model when posting the form back to a server action.

The actual version being used in the code doesn't pass the value of the property, it passes an expression which references the property itself:

```
m => m.CompanyName
```

So `TextBoxFor()` knows the model type, property type, annotations therein, etc.  That way it can use any additional information useful to the framework such as validation, helpful messages, type checking, etc.

Comment: I'm just not understanding here. I tried using Model.Company in the TextBoxFor and got a compilation error. It's a public property. Why is this considering that Model.Departments is also a public property that returns the list necessary to build the SelectList?

Comment: @tidjok: Surely the compiler error told you *why* it was failing?  I don't see any versions of the `TextBoxFor` method which accept *just* a string value as a parameter.  (For the reasons described in this answer, the value alone wouldn't provide enough information to the method.)  This has nothing to do with whether or not it's a public property.  C# is a statically typed language, you need to provide method parameters of the correct type.

Comment: Ok, I've done some additional reading and experimenting and I'm understanding what you mean. I was mistaken in thinking that TextBoxFor() accepted a value as the first parameter as opposed to the model reference. How does LINQ play into this? It seems to resemble a form of Reflection in this case.

Comment: In addition to this, how is the Model itself suddenly encapsulated in 'm'?

Comment: @tidjok: Conceptually one can think of it as being somewhat similar to something that can be accomplished via reflection, sure.  But don't think of it as really being related to LINQ at all.  The syntax is similar, but what you're building with `m => m.CompanyName` is simply an `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` object.  (Well, "simply" may be the wrong choice of word there.)  It's a strongly-typed lambda expression, which is also used in LINQ.  (Note: The first version of ASP.NET MVC allowed just passing a string, which was the property name.  It was a little sloppy.  Strong typing wins.)

Comment: @tidjok: `"how is the Model itself suddenly encapsulated in 'm'"` - That's a pretty good question, actually.  I don't know that off the top of my head.  It could be a convention built into the framework which "just works" in the context of a view.  With a potentially simple explanation behind it which I've never simply needed to find.

Comment: I think I need a solid tutorial on anonymous methods, lambda expressions and LINQ.

Comment: I understand that it's strongly-typed but how that expression object works exactly is feeling painful. Better to think of it as such though, that does clarify it a touch.

Comment: @tidjok: I could probably use one too :-P  If you can truly grok things like `Func<>`, `Action<>`, and `Expression<>` then you will find *a lot* of power in the language.  But even a casual understanding of them will get you very far with the built-in functionality, including things like LINQ and Entity Framework and MVC.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying at the moment. I'll look up all 3 and try to get a grasp. Is there any way to achieve the TextBoxFor() strongly-typed functionality *without* the lambda expression?

Comment: @tidjok: I don't see how.  Why would you want to omit the expression?

Comment: I just didn't see how these lambda expressions fit in. I spent quite a bit of time, and will spend more, focusing on Func<>, Action, Expression<>, delegates and anonymous methods. What I've managed to figure out somewhat is that the lambda expression is just shorthand for anonymous methods and that since you essentially have only 1 active and accessible object in your View, the Model, the lambda expression will always act upon just that.

Comment: Since the type of object is inferred from the lambda expression, that's how it knows and encapsulates the Model in your lefthand-side variable.

Comment: What also helped me is understanding that lambda expressions are either evaluated or parsed. In this case, I believe, they are only parsed. Messy stuff.